# Counting the number of two values following each other in a column in R

Tags: r

I want to know how can I count the number of times two elements follow each other in a column.

I have a data set of event and I want to group events that repeatedly happened after each other as the same event.

For example in:

`FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi
FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi
FreeWifi_secure
FreeWifi
FreeWifi_secure
HOME
HOME
HOME
HOME`

I want to assign `FreeWifi_secure` and `FreeWifi` to the same group.

Comment: Add some data and show expected output please.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?